# Free 64-bit disassembler?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, x86-64, disassembly

> #### **Note:** [A similar question is also on Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1817/16089).

Is there any free AMD64 disassembler?

It seems like there are a lot of x86 disassemblers, but they can't open 64-bit files...

#### Update:

Are there any tools that can show *exported* symbols in the disassembly as well? It's a little hard to figure out the code when the exports aren't identified. (I don't need debug symbols, just exports.)

Comment: Does Visual Studio Express not include the x64 toolkit?

Comment: @Cody: I'm not sure. I do have Visual Studio 2008 Professional, so that's not actually the issue for me here -- the issue here is that Visual Studio requires *running* the code, which I can't do.

Comment: Hmm, why can't you run the code? You don't have to have the source code, of course. You can just attach the debugger to an already-running process.

Comment: @Cody: It's kernel-mode code... and besides, you don't always want to *run* the code to figure out what it's doing. What if it's dangerous?!

Comment: @Mehrdad -- Run it in a VM.

Comment: You find a detailed answer here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/is-there-any-disassembler-to-rival-ida-pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArkDasm is a 64-bit interactive disassembler. Supported file types: PE64, raw binary files.

http://www.arkdasm.com/

You can examine imports, exports, debug symbols (if you have .pdb file), flip code to data, data to code (look at keyboards shortcuts in readme.pdf) has support for bookmarks, adding comments also you can save the database to work on it later...

Comment: Domain no longer exists.

Comment: It's still available for download at https://tuts4you.com/e107_plugins/download/download.php?view.3522

Answer (score 16):

I use `objdump -d`. :-) Does that not work for you?

Comment: +1 Whoa it definitely does, I never knew it could disassemble. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chris: A little question: Is there any way to make it label exported functions in the code? It's hard to make sense of the disassembly a little without them.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Oh, you mean dynamic symbols from a stripped executable? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Mehrdad: If it was built from regular ol' C code, they should already be there. Just for reference, here's the output I got from a dumb-simple .c file with just a foo() and main() function (just search for "foo": http://pastebin.com/49sYkv2q

Comment: @Mehdrad @Chris: D'oh, right, if the executable is stripped you're out of luck (I never strip my binaries except on embedded work, so I forget about that :().

Comment: @Nicholas: I tried disassembling `ntoskrnl.exe` but didn't see any function names... was I doing something wrong? (The *exports*, which I'm looking for, should always be there, you shouldn't need symbols for them...)

Answer (score 14):

If you're working with Windows files and have Visual Studio, you can use the dumpbin tool.

```
dumpbin /disasm ntoskrnl.exe /out:ntoskrnl.asm
```

It won't display exports inline either, but you can see them separately with the /exports switch. Then you can make a little script to parse the exports and replace the addresses in the assembly listing with names.

Comment: +1 thanks for the suggestion. It's a little tedious but if I have to do it I guess I might, thanks.

Comment: BTW, you can also use dbh.exe from Debugging Tools for Windows to fetch the .pdb file for ntoskrnl.exe and show symbols from it.

Answer (score 7):

[GNU binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) has `objdump`, [which should work](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/binutils/objdump.html#objdump):

> -d
>
> --disassemble
>
> Display the assembler mnemonics for
>   the machine instructions from objfile.
>   This option only disassembles those
>   sections which are expected to contain
>   instructions.
>
> -D
>
> --disassemble-all
>
> Like -d, but disassemble the contents
>   of all sections, not just those
>   expected to contain instructions. If
>   the target is an ARM architecture this
>   switch also has the effect of forcing
>   the disassembler to decode pieces of
>   data found in code sections as if they
>   were instructions.

It will already be installed on most Linux distributions that have GCC or other development tools installed, and Windows versions are available via e.g. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.duxcore.com/products.html

http://www.duxcore.com/fs_files/VisualDuxDbgSetup.zip

Visual DuxDebugger is a 64-bit debugger disassembler for Windows.

Main features
Fully support 64-bit native processes
Fully support 64-bit .NET processes
Full code analysis
Full memory analysis
Code edition
Memory edition
Module export formats (EXE/DLL/CSV)
Debug multiple processes
Debug multiple child processes

Minimum Requirements
O.S:          Windows 7 64-bit / Windows Server 2008 R2
Processor:    Pentium 4 3.0 GHz

Recommended Requirements
O.S:          Windows 7 64-bit / Windows Server 2008 R2
Processor:    Dual Core 2.5 GHz
Display:      1920 x 1080

Comment: unfortunately Visual DuxDebugger works only for 64 bit images...

Comment: Domain no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

WinDbg will dump the export table and let you poke around

```
windbg.exe -z \path\to\someinteresting.exe
x someinteresting!*
uf someinteresting!AnExportedFunction
```